# How to check the remaining buffer size of pipe in windows in c/c++?

Tags: windows, named-pipes

BTW the remaining buffer will automatically increase if the other side reads data out of it,right?

Answer (score 1):

How about [`PeekNamedPipe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365779(VS.85).aspx)? It would seem that the following will return the total number of bytes remaining to be read from the pipe.

```
DWORD totalBytesAvailable;
BOOL WINAPI PeekNamedPipe(
  handle,                // __in       HANDLE hNamedPipe,
  NULL,                  // __out_opt  LPVOID lpBuffer,
  0,                     // __in       DWORD nBufferSize,
  NULL,                  // __out_opt  LPDWORD lpBytesRead,
  &totalBytesAvailable,  // __out_opt  LPDWORD lpTotalBytesAvail,
  NULL                   // __out_opt  LPDWORD lpBytesLeftThisMessage
);
```

Comment: `totalBytesAvailable` includes bytes written by both sides of pipe,right?

Comment: @Alan: I'm not sure. It says its the total available to read, which might mean just what this side of the pipe can read. However, I think that this is one of those cases where the easiest way to find out definatively will be to write some test code.

Comment: It doesn't work,I just tried,`totalBytesAvailable` is always `0`

Comment: Maybe this is why `PeekNamedPipe` is reporting `0` to you:
The doc page for [`GetNamedPipeInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/namedpipeapi/nf-namedpipeapi-getnamedpipeinfo) (which the doc says can also work for anonymous pipes) says it can optionally report the "input" and "output" buffer sizes (total, not remaining). It also says it'll report `0` if the buffer grows on demand.